# What is a surface tangent?

Tags: shaders

The geometry node(shader node) has a tangent output, which to my understanding is the same as the tangent node output set to Z.
My question is now: what is a surface tangent? I know what a tangent is, but to my understanding a surface has an infinite amount of tangents, which is also why a plane is also sometimes described as all vectors that are perpendicular to a given normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tangent is a unit vector perpendicular to the normal (i.e. pointing along the surface) at each point on the surface. Anisotropic shaders have a tangent input that allows the user to specify ONE of the infinite possible values so that the shader knows which direction to emphasise specular highlights in.
The default direction in blender is the U direction if there is a UV map or a vector that wraps clockwise round the object's Z axis otherwise. More options are available via the Tangent node.
The shaders also allow adjustment of the direction in which they emphasise the highlight with an additional anisotropic rotation input, inconsistently using crazy units. See the blender manual!